# Como compartir memoria con otros programas

Tags: c++, c

Me refiero hacer algo como los punteros por refencia y trabajar con los mismos objetos.

Con la winapi lo mas que pude hacer es compartir int de 8 bytes.
Pero no objetos echos por mi.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que varios programas compartan una zona de memoria puedes usar lo que Microsoft llama Named Shared Memory. Una zona de memoria al que se le asigna un nombre que puede ser accedido desde varios programas diferentes. Tienes ayuda aquí:

[Creating Named Shared Memory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/creating-named-shared-memory)

Si lo que quieres es comunicación con funciones, esto es, que un programa llame a una función de otro programa, como cuando llamas a una función de una dll, puedes usar RPC. En este caso un proceso hace de servidor e implementa las funciones y otro u otros de clientes, que ejecutan las funciones. Sobre este tema hay mucho que leer e investigar.
Aquí tienes el enlace a la doc de Microsoft:

[Remote Procedure Call](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/Rpc/rpc-start-page)

Te recomiendo que busques ejemplos para empezar con algo. Empezar de cero puede ser muy frustrante porque no es sencillo a primera vista. Te dejo uno:

[Introduction to RPC - Part 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4837/Introduction-to-RPC-Part)

[Introduction to RPC - Part 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4878/Introduction-to-RPC-Part)

Comment: Compartir objetos, no simples cadenas de caracteres